# Is it possible to use the calling session inside a TensorFlow py_function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpflow

Basically, I'd like to know if something like the following code is safe.
I'd like to use `tf.py_function` to make a call to some scipy code, in which I'd like to evaluate ops of the calling session (including setting variables).  The reason is, I'd like to use bits of scipy code that do something that would be difficult to code in tensorflow, but where I don't want to interrupt the computation graph. I have at least two examples: one is utilising LSODE implicit ODE solver in a graph, and another is using scipy's robust minimizers in a graph (I'm thinking of calling GPFlow optimisers inside a py_function wrapper in an algorithm that requires repeatedly solving a GP optimisation problem).

The following code runs and returns what I expect (the value 1). But I don't know if it's safe. 
I'm guessing it gives non-deterministic behaviour if I were to also use the value of `x` elsewhere in the graph.

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import tensorflow as tf

def build_func(session, y_and_grad, var):
    pl = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    assign = tf.assign(var, pl)
    y, grad = y_and_grad
    def func(x):
        """
        This could be something that uses ops and vars in the same graph,
        but requires iterative access to session calls.
        E.g. using scipy.minimize with tensorflow to compute the gradients.
        """
        x = x.numpy()
        def fun_and_jac(x):
            session.run(assign,{pl:x})
            y, jac = session.run(y_and_grad)
            return y, jac
        res = minimize(fun_and_jac, x0=x, jac=True)
        return res.x
    return func

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as session:
    x = tf.Variable([0.], dtype=tf.float32)
    session.run(x.initializer)
    y = (x - 1.)**2
    grad = tf.gradients(y, x)[0]
    func = build_func(session, [y, grad], x)
    opt_x = tf.py_function(func, [x], [tf.float32])
    print(session.run(opt_x))
```